# How to make new cell based on appearance in dataframe cell

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to create new column in dataframe if a value is in existed column with array type and another column matches another condition. 
Dataset:

```
    name           loto
0  Jason           [22]
1  Molly          [222]
2   Tina          [232]
3   Jake          [223]
4    Amy  [73, 1, 2, 3]
```

If `name=="Jason"` and `loto` has 22 `new=1`

I tried to use `np.where`, but having issues check element in array.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'loto': [[22], [222], [232], [223], [73,1,2,3]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'loto'])
df['new'] = np.where((22 in df['loto']) & (df[name]=="Jason"), 1, 0)
```

Comment: You should generally avoid storing lists in a DataFrame column.  I would `explode` loto and filter that way.  That being said, the non-vectorized approach would be `[n == 'Jason' and 22 in l for n, l in zip(df.name, df.loto)]` which returns `[True, False, False, False, False]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create value you want to check in a set like `set([22])`

provide loto_chck in map and apply condition in `.loc`

```
loto_val = set([22])
loto_chck= loto_val.issubset
df.loc[(df['loto'].map(loto_chck))&(df['name']=='Jason'),"new"]=1
```

```
    name    loto     new
0   Jason   [22]        1
1   Molly   [222]       Nan
2   Tina    [232]       Nan
3   Jake    [223]       Nan
4   Amy [73, 1, 2, 3]   Nan
```

Comment: Thank you that works. Eventually I transformed array in string and used simple comparison operations. But method is good an useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```py
df['new'] = ((df.apply(lambda x : 22 in x.loto , axis = 1)) & \
             (df.name =='Jason')).astype(int)
```

Even though it's not a good idea to store lists in a dataframe